# Data table from array in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to convert this JavaScript code to Vue JS ES5. This is my Javascript that displays the table:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){

  // simple array
  var data = ["cat", "mouse", "bird", "goat", "monkey", "giraffe","cow","donkey","mice", "camel", "elephant", "bufalo", "jade","zebra","goose","hen","zat"];
  // html table
  var perrow = 4, // 7 items per row
      html = "<table><tr>";
  // Loop through array and add table cells
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    html += "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>";
    // Break into next row
    var next = i+1;
    if (next%perrow==0 && next!=data.length) {
      html += "</tr><tr>";
    }
  }
  html += "</tr></table>";

  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
});
```

how can I convert to vue js.
my vue code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var appVM= new Vue({
     el:'#app',
mydata:{["cat", "mouse", "bird", "goat", "monkey", "giraffe","cow","donkey","mice", "camel", "elephant", "bufalo", "jade","zebra","goose","hen","zat"]; 
     },
</script>
<table id="myTable"  class="display table" width="100%">
  <tbody> 
  <tr v-for="data in mydata">
        <td> data to appear in this section</td>    
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The sample code will fail because it has syntax errors in it: misplaced comma and missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: So you want to have the array entries laid out in a table with 4 entries on each row? As this isn’t really tabular data, why not use flexbox instead?

Answer (score 1):

By reading the manual: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

You need to take the following steps:

1. name the table `app` as a reference
2. Make sure the syntax is correct for the javaScript object inside the constructor function.
3. populate the data property with an object containing an array with key `mydata`
4. call the contents of an item with `{{ data }}` inside your `td`

```js
var appVM = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {mydata : ["cat", "mouse", "bird", "goat", "monkey", "giraffe", "cow", "donkey", "mice", "camel", "elephant", "bufalo", "jade", "zebra", "goose", "hen", "zat"]}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="app" class="display table" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="data in mydata">
      <td> {{ data }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, what i want is the data to be divided into columns and rows not one column. The javascript displays 4 columns and 5 rows

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking for a table based layout, but as the array doesn't really contain tabular data I would go with a CSS styled flexbox or grid based layout instead.

### Flex

```js
var appVM = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    entries : ["cat", "mouse", "bird", "goat", "monkey", "giraffe", "cow", "donkey", "mice", "camel", "elephant", "bufalo", "jade", "zebra", "goose", "hen", "zat"]
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.entry {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="entry in entries" class="entry">{{ entry }}</div>
</div>
```

### Grid

```js
var appVM = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    entries : ["cat", "mouse", "bird", "goat", "monkey", "giraffe", "cow", "donkey", "mice", "camel", "elephant", "bufalo", "jade", "zebra", "goose", "hen", "zat"]
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="entry in entries" class="entry">{{ entry }}</div>
</div>
```